# Why am I getting 400 bad request with AngularJs post?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC and AngularJs to create a web application. I send a request to the server but I am getting `400 error bad request`. I configure the message converter for the json format in the Spring servlet configuration file. I am wondering why I am getting this error.

Here is my angular service :

```
save : function(user) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/app-web/user/create',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:user
    });
}
```

And on the server side I have a Spring MVC Controller as described below :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/create", method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createAccount(@RequestBody User user){
  //some logic
    return "Ok";
}
```

I noticed something else: when I remove the `@RequestBody` in the controller I don't have a 400 error but the user is `null`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/create", method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createAccount(User user){
  //some logic
    return "Ok";
}
```

Comment: Does the "user" object that you are passing in, have a value or is it null?

Comment: i cannot reach the Spring MVC Controller. In the Angularjs controller user have value

Comment: If you use Chrome or IE and open the developer tools (F12) and put a breakpoint on the line "save : function(user) {". Run it and when the code hits the breakpoint, hover over "user". a tooltip appears with the value of the item you are hovering over.  Does it say null or does it have a value? Another thing to try is looking at the exact URL that it's trying to access (again, using developer tools).  The exact URL it's trying to access may be different than you were expecting.

Comment: Losbear i use firebug to see the value of user in angularjs side. user have value. But when the request is sent to server i have 400 bad request. When i remove the @RequestBody i reach the Spring Controller but user object does not contain value

Comment: ah, ok. so the "user" object doesn't match the user object being passed in on the clientside. Perhaps one of the properties on the clientside is null but the User object on the server side is not nullable.  Also check the casing of the names.  MVC tries to map it automatically for you, but if the object is too complex it can break easily. As a last resort (for kicks), comment out "public String createAccount(@RequestBody User user){" and replace with "public String createAccount(@RequestBody string user){" and pass a string with angular to see if it receives that.

Comment: The problem was about the user form. I had lastname, firstname, email, password, password1 but the User Java Object does not contains password1 attributes. Thanks

Comment: why don't you add your own answer, and remove all confusing xml parts from the question which is not relative?

Comment: @Losbear am having same problem, input which showing on firebug is 
{
  "id": null,
  "name": "qweqweqwe",
  "users": {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "Kaminee",
    "password": "1234",
    "email": "kim@mail .com",
    "address": "bhumkar ",
    "country": {
      "countryId": 1,
      "countryName": "India"
    }
  }
}
And My model contains exactly same fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was about the user form. I had lastname, firstname, email, password, password1 but the User Java Object does not contains password1 attributes. When json data provide by the request does not correspond to the Java Object, the JsonConverter is not able to match to data to Java Object.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Pracede I am having same problem, input which showing on firebug is 
{"id":null,"name":"qweqweqwe","users":{"id":3,"username":"Kaminee","password":"1234","email":"kim@mail
.com","address":"bhumkar ","country":{"countryId":1,"countryName":"India"}}}